# How can I automate COUNTIF formulas across multiple Google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation

Each release, a number of my reports help test for our engineering team, they are assigned cases in a google sheet and work through it.

Is there a way i can count the amount of times their name appears in a google sheet, from a separate sheet or app?

I know i could COUNTIF, but this would mean each week I'd have to go in, and write a bunch of countif formulas for the various people testing.

I was thinking there must be a way to write a script that searches for unique names in a column, then automatically writes the countif statements and prints them to a CSV or seperate sheet, but this is really the first thing I've tried to automate and am struggling to find the right info to get started, any direction or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello @Busyordead, you can use [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) to automate this task. Could you describe a bit more/present an example of what you are trying to accomplish? That would be of great help for us in providing a proper answer. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, so essentially there are multiple columns in which an agent can put their name if they've tested the case. So for instance the workbook for the release will have 12+ different sheets for different parts of the site, and an agent may work on multiple sheets. I need to make an automation to run on all sheets and add each unique name's cases together so that i have a clear "cases this release" stat. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`=QUERY()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) Google Sheets function along with row concatenation. As an example, having a worksheet that has 3 sheets (named respectively `Part1`, `Part2` and `Part3`) each of one having an issue column and an agent name column:

```
=QUERY({Part1!A2:B;Part2!A2:B;Part3!A2:B}, "SELECT Col2, COUNT(Col2) WHERE Col2 != '' GROUP BY Col2 LABEL Col2 'Agent', COUNT(Col2) 'Cases this release'")
```

#### Example

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### Result

[image]

You can see a working example of this feature in this public worksheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hrIMGsvSYOxHDoDCZNdYflE7PLh8Q_MOaeJBnr52tb8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you carlesgg97! I'll give this a shot tonight!

Comment: Looks like this doesn't actually SUM them in your example, the summary page is all single digits

Comment: In the example you can see the name "Enric" once in Part1, once in Part2 and twice in Part3 - resulting 4 in the Summary sheet. Is that different from what you expect @Busyordead?

Comment: Ahhh I see now. No, yours is correct, just had a brain fart. Thanks again!

Comment: @Busyordead No worries! :) Please consider [upvoting/accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) in case my answer was useful to you. Have a good day!

Comment: I did upvote but it says because im new that while it has been upvoted, it doesnt show publically, sorry!